# UML diagrams in Delphi

Tags: delphi, uml

Below is the code i wanted to model

```
  Class1 = class
  public
     type
       Class2 = class
       type
         Class3 = class
  end;
  end;
    end;
```

Below is the model RAD Studio IDE generated from the code
[http://www.freeimagehosting.net/newuploads/44170.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/44170)

I want to edit the inner classes using UML but there is no any options to do that , Even if i drag and drop a new class into an existing class , It resides inside correctly but there is no any proper way to define associations between the inner classes

Comment: is that only one level of Nested class are supported

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drag and drop class2 and class3 from Model View to diagram. Then you are able to edit the inner classes.